# Can't find array even though object is of array

Tags: java, arrays, object

So I'm trying to add 2 polynomials together, and I have created object type Polynomial of `ArrayBasedPoly`, and that object is an `array` of the coeff, and the degree is starting from 0.

Ex: `[1, 0, 3, 4] is 4x^3 + 3x^2 + 1`

In my add class, I'm trying to add the 2 arrays together ->

Ex: `p1 = [1, 0, 3, 4], p2 = [-2, -5], Sum[] = [-1, -5, 3, 4]`

However, in the add method, it won't recognize p2 as an array, even though the object is an array.

EDIT: Now I know that I need a method to find the length of the array of object p, however, even when I have a separate method, it still can't find it?

```
public class ArrayBasedPoly extends Polynomial
{
   private double [] poly; 

   public ArrayBasedPoly(double [] poly)
   {
      this.poly = poly;
   }

   public ArrayBasedPoly(double coeff, int expon)
   {
      super.coeff = coeff;
      super.expon = expon;
   }

   public ArrayBasedPoly add(ArrayBasedPoly p)
   {
      double [] temp = new double [Math.max(p.length, poly.length)]; //<=== Here
      return null; //temp
   }

   public String toString()
   {
      String s = "";

      if (poly == null)
      {
         return super.toString(); // no poly array
      }

      for(int i = poly.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
      {
         if (i != poly.length - 1 && poly[i] > 0) //adds + sign
         {
            s += " + ";
         }
         if (poly[i] != 0) // ignores the 0 in the array
         {
            if (i == 1) //if expon is 1, doesn't do the ^1
            {
               s += poly[i] + "x";
            } else if (i > 0) { // normal
               s += poly[i] + "x^" + i;
            } else {
               s += poly[i]; // if expon = 0, just prints out the coeff
            }   
         }   
      }
      return s;
   }

   public static void main (String [] args)
   {
      double [] c = {1, 0, 3, 4};
      double [] c1 = {-2, -5};

      Polynomial p1 = new ArrayBasedPoly (c);
      System.out.println("p1(x) =   " + p1);

      Polynomial p2 = new ArrayBasedPoly (c1);
      System.out.println("p2(x) =   " + p2);

      Polynomial p3 = new ArrayBasedPoly(-4, 1);
      System.out.println("p3(x) =   " + p3);

      Polynomial p = p1.add(p2);//.add(p2);
      System.out.println("p(x) =    " + p);

      Polynomial p4 = p.subtract(p3);
      System.out.println("p4(x) =   " + p4);

      Polynomial p5 = p4.getDerivative();
      System.out.println("p5(x) =   " + p5);

      System.out.println("p5(0) = " + p5.evaluate(0));
      System.out.println("p5(1) = " + p5.evaluate(1));
   }

} //ArrayBasedPoly
```

```js
public class Polynomial
{
   protected double coeff;
   protected int expon;
   
   public Polynomial()
   {
      coeff = 1;
      expon = 1;
      
   }
   
   public Polynomial(double coeff, int expon)
   {
      this.coeff = coeff;
      this.expon = expon;
   }
   
   public Polynomial(Polynomial p)
   {
      this.coeff = p.coeff;
      this.expon = p.expon;
   }
   
   public int getDegree()
   {
      return expon;
   }
   
   public double getCoeff()
   {
      return coeff;
   }
   
   public double evaluate(double x)
   {
      return Math.pow(x, expon) * coeff;
   }
   
   public Polynomial add (Polynomial p)
   {      
      Polynomial temp = new Polynomial();
      if (expon != p.expon)
      {
         return null;
      }
      temp.coeff = coeff + p.coeff;
      temp.expon = expon;   
      return temp;
   } //add
   
   public Polynomial subtract (Polynomial p)
   {
      Polynomial temp = new Polynomial();
      if (expon != p.expon)
      {
         return null;
      }
      temp.coeff = coeff - p.coeff;
      temp.expon = expon;
      return temp;
   } //subtract
   
   public Polynomial getDerivative()
   {
      Polynomial temp = new Polynomial(coeff, expon);
      if (expon == 1)
      {
         temp.coeff = coeff;
         temp.expon = 0;
         return temp;
      }
      temp.coeff *= temp.expon;
      temp.expon--;
      return temp;
   } //derivative
   
   public String toString()
   {
      if (expon == 0)
      {
         return coeff + "";   
      }
      if (expon == 1)
      {
         return coeff + "x";
      }
      return coeff + "x^" + expon;
   } //toString
   
   public static void main (String [] args)
   {
      //Coefficient, Exponent
      Polynomial p1 = new Polynomial(3, 2); //3x^2
      System.out.println("P1: " + p1);
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("Derivative of P1: " + p1.getDerivative());
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("P1 if x=2: " + p1.evaluate(2));
      Polynomial p2 = new Polynomial(2, 2);
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("P2: " + p2);
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("P1+P2: " + p1.add(p2));
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("P1-P2: " + p1.subtract(p2));
      Polynomial p3 = new Polynomial(2, 1);
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("P3: " + p3);
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("Derivative of P3: " + p3.getDerivative());
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("P1+P3: " + p1.add(p3));
   } //Main
   
} //Polynomial

/*
  ----jGRASP exec: java Polynomial
 P1: 3.0x^2
 
 Derivative of P1: 6.0x^1
 
 P1 if x=2: 12.0
 
 P2: 2.0x^2
 
 P1+P2: 5.0x^2
 
 P1-P2: 1.0x^2
 
 P3: 2.0x^1
 
 Derivative of P3: 1.0x^0
 
 P1+P3: null
 
  ----jGRASP: operation complete.
*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It seems like I have made an error, and that the "add" method should
>   have the parameter "Polynomial" instead because in the main method the
>   object are of type Polynomial. However, when I use the Polynomial
>   parameter and have a getLength() method, it still can't find it. –
>   Agramon

The problem is in the method call:

```
 Polynomial p = p1.add(p2);//.add(p2);
```

because p1 is a Polynomial it will check THAT class for the add method. You need to cast p1. And then you would need to cast p2 since the method is expecting an ArrayBasedPoly.

```
Polynomial p = ((ArrayBasedPoly) p1).add((ArrayBasedPoly) p2);
```

Comment: Thank you, if you saw my earlier comment, its because I typed it wrong.

Comment: Without seeing how you tried to cast it, I would guess you need to make sure you didn't miss the pair of parentheses that enclose **((ArrayBasedPoly) p1)** .  They're there to make sure the cast is applied to p1 and not the entire result.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple issues in this piece of code.

First, ArrayBasedPoly should not be extending Polynomial, as it is not a subclass of it, but an array representation of it. To solve this issue, you should keep an array/list of Polynomial inside ArrayBasedPoly like this:

```
public class ArrayBasedPoly {
    Polynomial[] polyArray;
    // or alternatively: List<Polynomial> polyArray;
    // or even better, use a sorted structure such as skiplist
}
```

Second, as Pereira pointed out, you are mixing up these two classes.
The Polynomial class does not contain add().
You can only add two ArrayBasePoly.

Comment: Can't find symbol? Btw, I changed the parameter from ArrayBasedPoly to Polynomial since the object in the main method is of type Polynomial